# How to iterate over a Row or Column of an Excel sheet using Python and look for specific value in cells?

Tags: python, excel, xlrd, xlwt

Below is a code I literally copied from someone. It reads and updates an existing Excel file. What I want is to add another functionality of iterating over each row or column and look for a specific value. Then I want to update that specific cell with a new value.

```
import xlwt
import xlrd
from xlutils.copy import copy

rb = xlrd.open_workbook("imtiaz.xls")
wb = copy(rb)
w_sheet = wb.get_sheet(0)
w_sheet.write(0,1,45)


w_sheet.write(1,1,46)
wb.save("imtiaz.xls")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To iterate over an excel sheet, you can use the `sheet.nrows()` function in the xlrd module.

```py
import xlrd

workbook = xlrd.open_workbook("my_path") # Opens your file
sheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0) # Gets the first sheet

for row in range(sheet.nrows): # Iterates over your sheet
    row_value = sheet.row_values(row)
    if row_value[1] == "my_value":
        print row_value
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use below logic as well. In last `data(List of List)` has all values in it. Each inner list represents the row.

```
import xlrd
book = xlrd.open_workbook('test.xlsx')
sheet = book.sheet_by_index(0)
data = []
for row in range(0, sheet.nrows):
    l = []
    for column in range(0, sheet.ncols):
        val = sheet.cell(row, column).value
        l.append(val)

    data.append(l)

print(data)
```